# alternative to `lapply` when applying function across columns

Tags: r

What is the correct method to apply a function across columns of a data frame?

I have some data similar to the following:

I want to compute a simple moving average for each column. I can use `lapply` but it puts the data as lists, if possible I would like to create new columns or a new data frame.

I have tried `sapply`, `mapply` etc.

Data:

```
require(quantmod)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(data.table)


from <- "2017-01-01"
to <- "2018-12-01"

symbols <- c('GOOG', 'MSFT', 'AAPL')

dataEnv <- new.env()
getSymbols(symbols, from=from, to = to, src = "yahoo", adjust = TRUE, env = dataEnv) 

data <- do.call(merge, eapply(dataEnv, Ad))
colnames(data) <- gsub(".Adjusted", "", colnames(data))

x <- lapply(data, function(x) SMA(x, n = 10))
```

For instance this creates a new column:

`data$googleSMA <- SMA(data$GOOG)`

Comment: If you are using `lapply`, you can use `df[] <- lapply(df, yourfunction)`

Comment: Using this creates a list of 1449 observations

Comment: `data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) SMA(x, n = 10))`

Comment: I didn't test your example.  I was saying about a single dataset.  i.e. `iris[] <- lapply(iris[1:3], cumsum)`

Comment: I want to add additional columns to the data, i.e. `GOOG.SMA`, `MSFT.SMA`, `AAPL.SMA` etc. instead of doing `data$googleSMA <- SMA(data$GOOG)` ...

Comment: I have issues in installing the `quantstrat` for testing

Comment: Apologies! the `quantstrat` package is not needed! I will edit the original post now with the only packages required.

Comment: Okay added the necessary packages, the `quantmod` package to get the data from Yahoo Finance, the `PerformanceAnalytics` to compute the `SMA` and the `data.table` to compute `do.call(merge, eapply(dataEnv, Ad))` (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an `xts` object.  `lapply` works on `data.frame` and `list`.  Here, we can use `apply`

```
apply(data, 2, SMA, n = 10)
```

Comment: Ah! I was trying this, (without the `2` however). What does the `2` do here? becase I was missing this part.

Comment: @user8959427  It is the `MARGIN` 2 - is for column and 1 - for rowwise